# What is stabilization of nanopartocles?

Tags: terminology, nanoscience

What is usually understood under the word "stabilization"? I know that nanoparticles can easily participate in the chemical reactions and unite one with another. And, for example, porous structures are used to stabilize them. But what exactly do we prevent nanoparticles from? Does it mean just to constrain chemical reactions and aggregation or also not to allow nanoparticles to move or transit to the other spacial isomer? Is it common to understand stabilization also as conservation of the phase state of the nanoparticle?

Sorry for my bad English.